# Group and aggregate SpatialPolygonsDataFrame by column in R

Tags: r, sp, rgdal

I'm working with `rgdal`, `sp`, `maptools`, `etc`.

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame that has each row/Polygons list with only one Polygon.  It also has an identifier column which I want to use to group by, and other attribute columns.

I would like to get the equivalent of group_by, where the attribute columns are aggregated, but where the corresponding Polygons' Polygon are concatenated in the same list.

Is there a function to do this?

Comment: `raster::aggregate` does approximately that

Comment: Thank you.  It indeed does.  Embarassed for having missed it.